# Calculating Aroon Indicator Series

Tags: c#, r, indicator, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to build a class to create Aroon series. But it seems I don't understand the steps well. I'm not sure about for what purpose I have to use the period parameter.

Here is my first attempt:

```
/// <summary>
/// Aroon
/// </summary>
public class Aroon : IndicatorCalculatorBase
{
    public override List<Ohlc> OhlcList { get; set; }
    public int Period { get; set; }

    public Aroon(int period) 
    {
        this.Period = period;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Aroon up: {((number of periods) - (number of periods since highest high)) / (number of periods)} x 100
    /// Aroon down: {((number of periods) - (number of periods since lowest low)) / (number of periods)} x 100
    /// </summary>
    /// <see cref="http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/112814/what-aroon-indicator-formula-and-how-indicator-calculated.asp"/>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override IIndicatorSerie Calculate()
    {
        AroonSerie aroonSerie = new AroonSerie();

        int indexToProcess = 0;

        while (indexToProcess < this.OhlcList.Count)
        {
            List<Ohlc> tempOhlc = this.OhlcList.Skip(indexToProcess).Take(Period).ToList();
            indexToProcess += tempOhlc.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < tempOhlc.Count; i++)
            {   
                int highestHighIndex = 0, lowestLowIndex = 0;
                double highestHigh = tempOhlc.Min(x => x.High), lowestLow = tempOhlc.Max(x => x.Low);
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (tempOhlc[j].High > highestHigh)
                    {
                        highestHighIndex = j;
                        highestHigh = tempOhlc[j].High;
                    }

                    if (tempOhlc[j].Low < lowestLow)
                    {
                        lowestLowIndex = j;
                        lowestLow = tempOhlc[j].Low;
                    }
                }

                int up = ((this.Period - (i - highestHighIndex)) / this.Period) * 100;
                aroonSerie.Up.Add(up);

                int down = ((this.Period - (i - lowestLowIndex)) / this.Period) * 100;
                aroonSerie.Down.Add(down);
            }
        }

        return aroonSerie;
   }
}
```

Is there anyone else tried to do that before?

Here is the csv file I use:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwv_-8Q17wGaRDVCa2FhMWlyRUk/view

But the result sets for Aroon up and down don't match with the results of aroon function in TTR package for R.

```
table <- read.csv("table.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
trend <- aroon(table[,c("High", "Low")], n=5)
View(trend)
```

Screenshot of R result:

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Expand your question to add exactly problem you are having.  What inputs are you giving? What are your expected outputs? What are your actual outputs?

Comment: How do your results differ from the R results?  I'm not an expert here, but the more information you give the better chance someone will be able to see why there's a discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@anilca,
for full Disclosure, I learned alot of things to answer your question(i knew nothing in the Finetec...). Thank you! it was an interesting experience!

There are several problems in your implementation:

1. In the statements:

> i - highestHighIndex

and

> i - lowestLowIndex

the variable "i" is less or equal to highestHighIndex, lowestLowIndex
so  statements:

> this.Period - (i - highestHighIndex)

and

> this.Period - (i - lowestLowIndex)

will returns the wrong values (most of the time...)

2. Aroon up and down both of them are percentage, therefore "int" is a wrong data structure.
3. Because all variables in:

> (this.Period - (i - highestHighIndex)) / this.Period)

and

> ((this.Period - (i - lowestLowIndex)) / this.Period)

are integers you won't recieve the right value.

4. one more thing the numbers in your excel are sorted from the newest to the oldest.(it effects on the R package)

I've implemented the algorithm based on your code(and your data order...)

```
public class Aroon : IndicatorCalculatorBase
{

    public override List<OhlcSample> OhlcList { get; set; }
    private readonly int _period;

    public int Period
    {
        get { return _period; }
    }

    public Aroon(int period)
    {
        _period = period;
    }

    public override IIndicatorSerie Calculate()
    {
        var aroonSerie = new AroonSerie();
        for (var i = _period; i < OhlcList.Count; i++)
        {

            var aroonUp = CalculateAroonUp(i);
            var aroonDown = CalculateAroonDown(i);

            aroonSerie.Down.Add(aroonDown);
            aroonSerie.Up.Add(aroonUp);
        }

        return aroonSerie;
    }

    private double CalculateAroonUp(int i)
    {
        var maxIndex = FindMax(i - _period, i);

        var up = CalcAroon(i - maxIndex);

        return up;
    }

    private double CalculateAroonDown(int i)
    {
        var minIndex = FindMin(i - _period, i);

        var down = CalcAroon(i - minIndex);

        return down;
    }

    private double CalcAroon(int numOfDays)
    {
        var result = ((_period - numOfDays)) * ((double)100 / _period);
        return result;
    }

    private int FindMin(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        var min = double.MaxValue;
        var index = startIndex;
        for (var i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        {
            if (min < OhlcList[i].Low)
                continue;

            min = OhlcList[i].Low;
            index = i;
        }
        return index;
    }

    private int FindMax(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        var max = double.MinValue;
        var index = startIndex;
        for (var i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        {
            if (max > OhlcList[i].High)
                continue;

            max = OhlcList[i].High;
            index = i;
        }
        return index;
    }
}

public abstract class IndicatorCalculatorBase
{
    public abstract List<OhlcSample> OhlcList { get; set; }

    public abstract IIndicatorSerie Calculate();
}

public interface IIndicatorSerie
{
    List<double> Up { get; }
    List<double> Down { get; }
}

internal class AroonSerie : IIndicatorSerie
{
    public List<double> Up { get; private set; }
    public List<double> Down { get; private set; }

    public AroonSerie()
    {
        Up = new List<double>();
        Down = new List<double>();
    }


}

public class OhlcSample
{

    public double High { get; private set; }
    public double Low { get; private set; }

    public OhlcSample(double high, double low)
    {
        High = high;
        Low = low;
    }

}
```

Use this test method for debugging:

```
    private Aroon _target;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        _target=new Aroon(5)
        {
            OhlcList = new List<OhlcSample>
            {
                new OhlcSample(166.90, 163.65),
                new OhlcSample(165.00, 163.12),
                new OhlcSample(165.91, 163.21),
                new OhlcSample(167.29, 165.11),
                new OhlcSample(169.99, 166.84),
                new OhlcSample(170.92, 167.90),
                new OhlcSample(168.47, 165.90),
                new OhlcSample(167.75, 165.75),
                new OhlcSample(166.14, 161.89),
                new OhlcSample(164.77, 161.44),
                new OhlcSample(163.19, 161.49),
                new OhlcSample(162.50, 160.95),
                new OhlcSample(163.25, 158.84),
                new OhlcSample(159.20, 157.00),
                new OhlcSample(159.33, 156.14),
                new OhlcSample(160.00, 157.00),
                new OhlcSample(159.35, 158.07),
                new OhlcSample(160.70, 158.55),
                new OhlcSample(160.90, 157.66),
                new OhlcSample(164.38, 158.45),
                new OhlcSample(167.75, 165.70),
                new OhlcSample(168.93, 165.60),
                new OhlcSample(165.73, 164.00),
                new OhlcSample(167.00, 164.66),
                new OhlcSample(169.35, 165.01),
                new OhlcSample(168.12, 164.65),
                new OhlcSample(168.89, 165.79),
                new OhlcSample(168.65, 165.57),
                new OhlcSample(170.85, 166.00),
                new OhlcSample(171.61, 169.10)
            }
        };
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void JustToHelpYou()
    {
        var result = _target.Calculate();

        var expectedUp = new List<double>()
        {
            100,80,60,40,20,0,0,0, 0,0,40,20,0,100,100,100,100,80, 60,100,80,60,40,100,100
        };

        var expectedDown = new List<double>
        {
            20,0,0,100,100,80,100,100,100,100,80,60,40,20,0,0,40,20,0,0,40,20,0,40,20
        };

        Assert.IsTrue( result.Up.SequenceEqual(expectedUp));
        Assert.IsTrue( result.Down.SequenceEqual(expectedDown));

    }
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot! I asked the same question here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/technical-analysis-calculating-aroon-indicator-serie If you want you can add your answer there too.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add implementation of method HighestBarNum and LowestBarnum from your code

```
 public class Aroon 
{  
    public bool AroonDown
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public double Period
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Aroon()
    {
    }
    public IList<double> Execute(IList<double> src)
    {
        if (!this.AroonDown)
        {
            return this.ExecuteUp(src);
        }
        return this.ExecuteDown(src);
    }
    public IList<double> ExecuteDown(IList<double> src)
    {
        double[] period = new double[src.Count];
        for (int i = 1; i < src.Count; i++)
        {
            double num = LowestBarNum(src, i, Period);
            period[i] = 100 * (Period - num) / Period;
        }
        return period;
    }
    public IList<double> ExecuteUp(IList<double> src)
    {
        double[] period = new double[src.Count];
        for (int i = 1; i < src.Count; i++)
        {
            double num = HighestBarNum(src, i, Period);
            period[i] = 100 * ((Period - num) / Period;
        }
        return period;
    }}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to implement LowestBarNum and HighestBarNum methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AroonData
{
    public double AroonUp;

    public double AroonDown;
}
```

Calculation Class:

```
class AroonCalculationData
{
    public double PeriodHigh;

    public double PeriodLow;

    public double SetAroonUp(List<MarketData> period, double lastHigh)
    {

        /*reverse the set so we can look at it from the current tick
        on back, and ticksSinceHigh will set correctly*/
        period.Reverse();

        int ticksSinceHigh = 0;
        double high = 0.0;//Set 0 so anything will be higher

        for (int i = 0; i < period.Count; i++)
        {
            if (period[i].high > high)
            {
                high = period[i].high;
                ticksSinceHigh = i;
            }
        }

        /*This bit if for if the high just ticked out
        of List<MarketData>.
        Including the current tick (i = 0), List<MarketData> period
        only looks back (period - 1) days. 
        This Checks to see if the last high is still in the set. if it's 
        not, and is still the high for the period, then ticksSinceHigh
        is set to (period)*/
        PeriodHigh = high;
        if (PeriodHigh < lastHigh)
        {
            ticksSinceHigh = period.Count;
        }

        /*Aroon-Up Formula*/
        return (double)(period.Count - ticksSinceHigh ) / (double)period.Count * 100.0;
    }

    //ASIDE FROM LOOKING FOR LOWS INSTEAD OF HIGHS, SAME AS AROON-UP
    public double SetAroonDown(List<MarketData> period, double lastLow)
    {

        period.Reverse();

        int daysSinceLow = 0;
        double low = double.MaxValue;//Set max so anything will be lower

        for (int i = 0; i < period.Count; i++)
        {
            if (period[i].low < low)
            {
                low = period[i].low;
                daysSinceLow = i;
            }
        }

        PeriodLow = low;
        if (PeriodLow > lastLow)
        {
            daysSinceLow = period.Count;
        }

        return (double)(period.Count - daysSinceLow) / (double)period.Count * 100.0;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
public AroonData[] Aroon(List<MarketData> marketData, int period)
{
    AroonCalculationData[] calculationData = new AroonCalculationData[marketData.Count]
    AroonData[] aroon= new AroonData[marketData.Count]

    for (int i = period; i < marketData.Count; i++)
    {
        /*GetRange(i - period + 1, period) add 1 so that the current tick is 
        included in look back.
        For example, if (period = 10) the first loop (i = 10) then (i - 
        period + 1) = 1 the set will be marketData 1 - 10.*/

        /*calculationData[i - 1].PeriodHigh and calculationData[i - 1].PeriodLow
        are for looking back at the last tick's look back period high and 
        low*/

        data[i].AroonUp = calculationData[i].SetAroonUp(marketData.GetRange(i - period + 1, period), calculationData[i - 1].PeriodHigh);
        data[i].AroonDown = calculationData[i].SetAroonDown(marketData.GetRange(i - period + 1, period), calculationData[i - 1].PeriodLow);
    }
}
```

Side note:
One problem I had was comparing my data to TD Ameritrades Aroon, until i figured out their period is really period-1, so if you're comparing to TD keep that in mind.